# javascript, selecting one value from object that starts with specific letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am selecting all classes from an attribude like so:

```
var sOption = $(this).attr('class');
```

in console.log it returns `test_1 custom_selectbox`

From this i want it to select the class that starts with `test_`, so with this example it would only return `test1`. I did the following like so:

```
var sOption = $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('custom_selectbox',''));
```

In this sittuation it returns what i want, but if i add more classes to the attribute where it takes the classes, i would need to also add those class names into replace area:

```
var sOption = $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('custom_selectbox','' , 'more_classes', '', 'and_so_on' , ''));
```

What i want is - instead of using `trim` and `replace` , get the `test_` classes from the object using regular expressions (bad example):

```
var sOption = $(this).attr('class'); //get the `test_1 custom_selectbox`
//somehow use the regular expression on this object, so it would select an item from sOption that starts with `test_`
```

Hopefully i made it understandable what im looking for..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may `split` the string into an array, using space as item delimiter, and then `filter` that array for elements that match your string:

```
"test_1 custom_selectbox"
     .split(' ')
     .filter(function(x) { return x.indexOf('test_') == 0; })
```

You could of course extract that to a plugin:

```
$.fn.getClasses = function(prefix) {
    return $(this).attr('class').split(' ').filter(function(x) { return x.indexOf(prefix) == 0; });
};
```

Called like so:

```
$(this).getClasses('test_');
```